# Spring Boot HttpSecurity problem with exceptionHandling

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

problem with exceptionHandling:

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .exceptionHandling(excHand -> excHand.accessDeniedPage("/error/403"))
                .csrf(csrfCustomizer->csrfCustomizer.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                .requestMatchers("/").hasAnyRole("USER")
                                        )
                .formLogin(formLogin -> formLogin
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                        )
                .logout(logout -> logout.logoutUrl("/logout")
                .permitAll()
                        )
                .build();

    }
```

Some Logs are:

```
Exception:
jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Filter execution threw an exception
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:110)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:110)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:110)

Root Cause:

java.lang.StackOverflowError
    java.base/java.nio.Buffer.<init>(Buffer.java:245)
    java.base/java.nio.ByteBuffer.<init>(ByteBuffer.java:288)
    java.base/java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:78)
    java.base/java.nio.ByteBuffer.wrap(ByteBuffer.java:408)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.toStringInternal(ByteChunk.java:584)
```

I need a fix or alternative people, thanks
I can't redirect to a custom access denied page.

Comment: Please also provide the logs, i mean stack trace of problem

Comment: Hi, i put some logs now, thanks Andrei

Comment: Can you add some more details ?  I mean all the stack trace started from here `java.lang.StackOverflowError`

Comment: By the way, have you tried my answer yet ? If yes, did it help ?

Comment: Yes, i have the same problem, it's kinda weird.  I try to redirect to access denied page. e.g. "user" don't have permission for  [URL]/add.

Comment: ok just provide more stack trace i am going to look through and help you

Comment: External link, Andrei

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: invalid link, just update the question with full trace

Comment: It's too long, Andrei

Comment: GitHub link of the project please

Comment: and also if you will remove `.exceptionHandling(excHand -> excHand.accessDeniedPage("/error/403"))` will it work ?

Comment: It works, thanks Andrei. Another way to redirect to a 403 page?

Comment: Do you have a custom 403 handling page ?

Comment: Yes, but we are going to put this in another post. Thanks Andrei

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem that you have is in this part of configuration:

```
.formLogin(formLogin -> formLogin
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
```

because usually when we are going to write it so, we have a custom login page mapped to `/login` according to [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/form.html). And also we should declare a `@GetMethod` that match our implementation also according to documentation.

To be sure in my explanation, you can rewrite the `securityFilterChain`. Something like this:

```
  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
        .exceptionHandling(excHand -> excHand.accessDeniedPage("/error/403"))
        .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
        .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
            .requestMatchers("/**").hasAnyRole("USER")
        )
        .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())
        .logout(Customizer.withDefaults())
        .build();

  }
```

After it you will be able to open the login page that is mapped on default path `/login`.

Also these rules is applied to `logout`.